# Using Spreadsheet::XLSX, how do I copy formats from one worksheet to another?

Tags: perl, spreadsheet, xlsx, formats

I'm using Perl v5.12.3 on Mac OSX Lion.  I'm using the latest version of the Spreadsheet::XLSX module.  How do you copy existing worksheet row, column, and cell formats from one XLSX file to a new file?  For cells, I'm currently trying

```
                        my $cell = $oldWorksheet -> {Cells} [$row] [$col];
                        ...
                        $newWorksheet->write( $newWorksheetCurRow, $col, $val, $cell->{Format} )
```

But it isn't working.  For example, the background colors aren't getting copied and I don't even think "{Format}" is a valid attribute of the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spreadsheet::XLSX doesn't read cell formats so it isn't possible to copy a worksheet formatting like this.

As far as I know there isn't any Perl module, apart from Win32::OLE that reads formatting from an XLSX file.

I'm [working on one](https://github.com/jmcnamara/excel-reader-xlsx) but formatting support is several months away.

Answer (score 0):

If it's like SpreadSheet::WriteExcel/ParseExcel, then you have to do it all manually. That is, create a new format on the writer side, then copy in all the attributes of the format from the parsed side.

Comment: How do I programatically get the format attributes from the parsed side?  I'm not able to find any documentation or examples on this.